# How to check if a Facebook graph api request has completed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

How do i check if I have received a reply for the following graph api request?

```
 $abc=$facebook->api('/'.$userid);
```

also what are the keys inside $abc if I have received an error?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read [Getting Started: The Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/). Try your queries with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) as well. In case you get an error, it depends on your query. If the user id is unknown for example, you receive the following output:

```
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
```

You should check, if the "id"-key is set and not empty.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i check if I have received a reply for the following graph api request?

Checking if the request has “completed”, as you say in the title, is moot – the PHP SDK API calls are **synchronous**, so the execution of your code always “waits” until the response from the API is received.

> also what are the keys inside $abc if I have received an error?

None – the value will be just `null`.

The PHP SDK throws **exceptions** when something went wrong – so familiarize yourself with how to work with those in PHP using `try { … } catch(…) { … }` statement blocks.

Comment: I am not receiving any response. The code just stops executing for a long time at the same statement. It does not throw an exception either.  Shall I assume that my requests will still be returned?

Comment: If it _“stops for a long time”_, does that mean it eventually returns a result? Or does the script get aborted? If the latter, check your error logs, resp. activate error_reporting, so that PHP will notify you about issues.

Comment: I finally got around the problem. I was actually getting a cURL SSL connection timeout error which i solved by increasing the connection timeout parameter in the base_facebook file